# FAA NOTAM via JMS web based?

Tags: java, jms, solace

now I download recent NOTAMs (Notice to Airman) from FAA PilotWeb scraping the webpage like this: [link](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&formatType=ICAO&retrieveLocId=EDFH&reportType=RAW&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs)

By simple php script and a cron-job I can save NOTAMs I want in a database.

But from January 24, 2020 FAA will swtich off PilotWeb and NOTAMs will be made available through [NOTAM Search](https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/) that can not be scraped (isn't it?). They will allow to download NOTAMs only by [SWIM Cloud Distribution](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/technology/swim/products/get_connected/) via **JMS**.

At the moment I don't know Java and JMS. My questions are: can I make a web-based script to download NOTAMs via JMS? I use a standard web hosting and I don't know how to use java on web hosting. Is it possible?

[...]

Comment: No. JMS is a messaging system (not a web framework). No, it's not possible. Don't know how to test whatever random "jumpstart" you downloaded. No, requests for tutorials and other off-site resources are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is just an API. It's not a protocol. The particular implementation you're using (i.e. Solace) and it's underlying wire protocol will determine whether or not you can use it from a JavaScript client. As long as your JavaScript client can speak the right protocol you should be able to access the Solace broker regardless of if you use Java or JMS.

Solace provides a JavaScript API. See [the documentation](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/js/index.html) for more details.